# VB.Net TcpClient error - The requested address is not valid in its context

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient

I am trying to implement a TcpClient and keep getting the error

> The requested address is not valid in its context

This, however, only happens if I place the code inside a class that is called by the main form. When I place the code in the main form (in the form load event), the error does not occur and communication over the TcpClient is successfull.

I have tried to decorate the class with Inherits ApplicationContext but the error is still thrown. heres the code I am using:

1. The class

   ```
   Public Class dasharClient

      Inherits ApplicationContext

       Public port As Integer
       Public hostname As String
       Private myClient As TcpClient
       Sub New()
           myClient = New TcpClient(hostname, port)
           Dim subscribe As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World")
           myClient.GetStream.BeginWrite(subscribe, 0, subscribe.Length, AddressOf MyWriteCallBack, myClient.GetStream)
       End Sub
       Public Sub MyWriteCallBack(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
           CType(ar.AsyncState, NetworkStream).EndWrite(ar)
      End Sub
   End Class
   ```
2. I initialize the class from the main form thus

   ```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

       Dim testClass As New dasharClient With {.port = 3354, .hostname = "my.domain.com"}

   End Sub
   ```

As noted above, if I put the code inside the class into the form load event sub (without the class decoration), it works!

Comment: Did u try printing the hostname? I think its empty when u get that error.

Comment: @dvasanth - the hostname is not empty. If you look at the lower code, I initialise the class with a hostname (and it resolves the IP correctly!)

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with your NEW syntax.  I'm not familiar with NEW WITH, but from what I've read it's creating an object of anonymous class and not a new object of dasharClient class.  Maybe Dim testClass as New dasharClient(3354, "my.domain.com"), and then in the dasharClient, create a Sub New(port as Integer, hostname as String) constructor.